# No matching distribution found for pickle when using requirements.txt and Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku

I am using Heroku to try to deploy my app. After connecting to my Github repo, then under “Manual deploy”, I hit “Deploy Branch”

The Github repo contains `requirements.txt` which contains

```
numpy
pandas
matplotlib
pickle
gunicorn
flask
```

The error on Heroku says

```
   Collecting pickle (from -r /tmp/build_0f73c7cf93d0cf7e0d53415c51d2e21f/requirements.txt (line 4))

     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle (from -r /tmp/build_0f73c7cf93d0cf7e0d53415c51d2e21f/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: )

   No matching distribution found for pickle (from -r /tmp/build_0f73c7cf93d0cf7e0d53415c51d2e21f/requirements.txt (line 4))



!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

 !     Push failed
```

Yet, `pickle` seems to be installed on my Ubuntu machine. When I type `python` on the terminal, and then `import pickle`, I don't see any errors

Also, when I try

```
filename = 'outfile.pickle'
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
pickle.dump(dataframe,outfile)
outfile.close()
```

I see the pickle file in my directory

Why am I getting this error in Heroku?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate problem is that [`pickle` is a module in Python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle). There is no need to install it (and therefore no need to include it in your `requirements.txt` file).

It's generally a good idea to install dependencies locally from the same dependency file as you use in production. This will uncover issues like this, where you have an entry that shouldn't be there.

However, you probably shouldn't be running this code on Heroku even if you can get it to build. Heroku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). The files you save will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This happens frequently ([at least once per day)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts).

You can save data in a client-server database like [Heroku's Postgres service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), or if you really need to save files [Heroku recommends using something like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).